# Module Runs in the Wrong Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm trying to copy some cells from one workbook and paste them in another with this code:

```
Sub Finder()
Range("C2").Value = "Measurement"
Range("C2").ColumnWidth = 13

Range("D2").Value = "Unit"
Range("D2").ColumnWidth = 5

Range("E2").Value = "Balloon"
Range("E2").ColumnWidth = 8

Range("F2").Value = "Nominal Value"
Range("F2").ColumnWidth = 14

Range("G2").Value = "+Tolerance"
Range("G2").ColumnWidth = 11

Range("H2").Value = "-Tolerance"
Range("H2").ColumnWidth = 11

Range("I2").Value = "Pass/Fail"
Range("I2").ColumnWidth = 8

Range("C2:I2").Font.Bold = True
Range("C2:I2").HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter

With Range("C2:I2").Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
    End With

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Documents\Keyence\Book.xlsx")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Documents\Keyence\Finder.xlsm")

x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C18:I18").Copy

y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Whenever I run the code, however, it copies the code from Book.xlsx and pastes it into the correct range, but in Book.xlsx instead of in Finder.xlsm. 
I also have some cell formatting code before the copy/paste section, and that code is executed in both Finder.xlsm and Book.xlsx.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I create a kind of this code this morning, look at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50693655/excel-vba-open-workbook-copy-and-add-to-last-line-on-another-workbook/50694303#50694303

Comment: What if you use: `x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C18:I18").Copy y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3")` instead?

Comment: Your code looks correct. Where is this `Sub Finder()` running in? Is it a third workbook or is it `Finder.xlsm`? If it is `Finder.xlsm` use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").PasteSpecial` and remove the `Set y` because this workbook is already open then.

Comment: I got rid of the `Set y` and added in `ThisWorkbook.Sheet("Sheet1").Range("C3").PasteSpecial` instead of `y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").PasteSpecial` and that fixed the problem. with the pasting in the wrong sheet. The only thing now is that the cell formatting code is still running in both workbooks. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @JonathanSedlacek I see no cell formatting code. [Edit] your question and provide the relevant code, otherwise we cannot help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve my problem of the code pasting the copied information in Book.xlsx instead of in Finder.xlsx where it is intended to go, I deleted the `Set y = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Documents\Keyence\Finder.xlsm")` section and replaced the `y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C3").PasteSpecial` section with `ThisWorkbook.Sheet("Sheet1").Range("C3").PasteSpecial`. This change caused the information to be pasted to the correct cells in the correct workbook.

To solve the issue of the formatting code modifying both Finder.xlsx (which it is supposed to do) and Book.xlsx (which it is not supposed to do), I used @PEH's advice. At first the code looked something like this:

```
Sub Finder()
Range("C2").Value = "Measurement"
Range("C2").ColumnWidth = 13
Range("D2").Value = "Unit"
Range("D2").ColumnWidth = 5
```

But this code did not specify where the formatting was supposed to take place, so it just guessed. In order to get around this, I changed it to look something like this:

```
Sub Setup()
Dim WsToFormat As Worksheet
Set WsToFormat = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With WsToFormat
    .Range("C2:D2").Interior.Color = RGB(83, 235, 231)
    .Range("C4").Value = "Date/Time"
    .Range("D4").Value = "Measurement"
    .Range("D4").ColumnWidth = 13
End With
End Sub
```

This tells the formatting code which workbook and worksheet need to be formatted.

The final code with both fixes looks like this:

```
Sub Finder()
Dim WsToFormat As Worksheet
Set WsToFormat = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With WsToFormat
    .Range("C2:D2").Interior.Color = RGB(83, 235, 231)
    .Range("C4").Value = "Date/Time"
    .Range("D4").Value = "Measurement"
    .Range("D4").ColumnWidth = 13
End With

With Range("C2:D2").Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThin
End With

Dim x As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\me\Documents\Keyence\Book.xlsx")
x.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C18:I18").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheet("Sheet1").Range("C3").PasteSpecial

End Sub
```

Hope this helps anyone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not specify in which worksheet the ranges are, Excel starts guessing which one you meant the range to be in (and it might guess wrong).

So best is always to specify a workbook (if different from `ThisWorkbook`) and the worksheet the range is in.

For example:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName").Range("C2").Value = "Measurement"
```

If you use the same sheet multiple times it would be better to set a variable for it (or at least use a `With` statement:

```
Dim WsToFormat As Worksheet
Set WsToFormat = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName")

With WsToFormat
    .Range("C2").Value = "Measurement"
    .Range("C2").ColumnWidth = 13
End With
```

Note that the dot `.` in the beginning of the `.Range` means to trigger the `With` statement.

Comment: Awesome, This helped the formatted cells to only appear in the correct workbook/worksheet. Thanks

Comment: @Jonathan If this solved your issue please mark the answer as solution, so everyone can see that it was solved.